# Evaluate single line of python code from Emacs org-babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python, ess

Consider a block of python code in an `org-mode` document:

```
#+begin_src python

num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter another number: ")
result = float(num1) + float(num2)
print(result)

#+end_src
```

If I were to open a similar block of `R`code in `org-edit-special` I could use `ess-eval-line` to run this line-by-line or `ess-eval-region` to run a highlighted region.

How can I get similar functionality for blocks of code, written in python?

Comment: Maybe edit the question? For now setting :results output and M-x org-babel-execute-src-block RET will do it.

Answer (score 1):

From within `org-edit-special`, I found that you can evaluate a highlighted region by running `python-shell-send-region` (which should default to `C-c C-r`). As for evaluating an single line, I wrote my own function, `python-shell-send-line`, which I load from `init.el`:

```
;; Add a function to send a single line to the Python console
(defun python-shell-send-line ()
  (interactive)
  (save-mark-and-excursion
    (move-beginning-of-line nil)
    (set-mark-command nil)
    (move-end-of-line nil)
    (python-shell-send-region
     (region-beginning)
     (region-end))))

;; Create shortcut
(with-eval-after-load "python" (define-key python-mode-map
                 (kbd "C-c C-j")
                 'python-shell-send-line))
```

Comment: What is wrong with Andreas Röhler's suggestion of adding `:results output` and pressing `C-c C-c`?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, that would evaluate the entire block. I was looking for a way to evaluate a single line of code and also a marked region.

Comment: OK - I see. I didn't read the question carefully enough.